# Regex to capture content between []

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a big json and i want to remove all content between [ ], example:

```
"arrow-alt-circle-down": [
        512,
        512,
        [],
        "f358",
        "M504 256c0 137-111 248-248 248S8 393 8 256 119 8 256 8s248 111 248 248zM212 140v116h-70.9c-10.7 0-16.1 13-8.5 20.5l114.9 114.3c4.7 4.7 12.2 4.7 16.9 0l114.9-114.3c7.6-7.6 2.2-20.5-8.5-20.5H300V140c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-64c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12z"
    ],
```

This content, i want to capture with regex:

```
        512,
        512,
        [],
        "f358",
        "M504 256c0 137-111 248-248 248S8 393 8 256 119 8 256 8s248 111 248 248zM212 140v116h-70.9c-10.7 0-16.1 13-8.5 20.5l114.9 114.3c4.7 4.7 12.2 4.7 16.9 0l114.9-114.3c7.6-7.6 2.2-20.5-8.5-20.5H300V140c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-64c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12z"
```

I tried with `\[(.*?)\]` but only capture the empty []

Comment: Yeah but i want to remove this content, not use it

Comment: @lurker No effect

Comment: If your input is multiline as shown, then you need to use a multiline option for regex. Check the documentation.

Comment: I dont know how to do that

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco this has selected all, not only [ ] content

Comment: Can you try this one: `/([^\[])(.+)([^\]])/gm`

Comment: @FlavioFrancisco same result

Comment: Maybe `/\[((\n.*)+)\]/gm`

Answer (score 2):

In the comments, the op clarified they want to remove the field

> i want to remove this content, not use it

You can either set `jsObj["arrow-alt-circle-down"] = undefined;`, or even better, use the `delete` operator ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).

```js
let jsObj = {
 "arrow-alt-circle-down": [
  512,
  512,
  [],
  "f358",
  "M504 256c0 137-111 248-248 248S8 393 8 256 119 8 256 8s248 111 248 248zM212 140v116h-70.9c-10.7 0-16.1 13-8.5 20.5l114.9 114.3c4.7 4.7 12.2 4.7 16.9 0l114.9-114.3c7.6-7.6 2.2-20.5-8.5-20.5H300V140c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-64c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12z"
 ],
 "other-fields": "preserved",
};

delete jsObj['arrow-alt-circle-down'];
console.log(jsObj);
```

Comment: Agreed - manipulating the data as a string and then parsing it back into data is very weird.  This is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
/(?<=\[)([^)]+)(?=\])/gm
```

you can use https://regex101.com/ to play around with regex